# React JS - JSX returns [object Object] instead of string

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Why this JSX hook returns [object Object] [object Object]  instead of HTML string?

```
export default function Article (props) {

  const {
    content,
  } = props;

  console.log({content});

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {content.replace(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g, (match) => {
          return (
              <p className="text-black">{match}</p>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Console.log print:

```
{
  content: '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas dignissim ac ante nec hendrerit.</p>\n' +
    '\n' +
    '<p>Morbi rhoncus diam quis sodales iaculis. Morbi ullamcorper consectetur ultricies. Nam vel efficitur erat.</p>'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

> Why this JSX hook returns `[object Object] [object Object]` instead of
> HTML string?

You are attempting to render the returned of `content.replace` but the function you use to replace is returning a JSX object instead of a new string. You are also copying the entire match instead of just the captured group.

## Solution

It is very unclear to me what you are trying to do, or why, but if you want to modify the raw HTML you can do a string replace, but you need to then use standard HTML (not JSX!!) and set the innerHTML of the div. Here you need to specify `class` instead of `className`.

```
<div
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: content.replace(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g, (match, p1) => {
      return `<p class="text-black">${p1}</p>`;
    })
  }}
></div>
```

or a bit more simple without the updater function

```
<div
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: content.replace(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g, '<p class="text-black">$1</p>')
  }}
></div>
```

## Demo

[image: Edit react-js-jsx-returns-object-object-instead-of-string]